# MongoDB - Mongoose query findOneAndUpdate() doesn't update/duplicates the DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save and update `findOneAndUpdate()` (`{upsert: true}` - creates the object if it doesn't exist) the result of the Web Api which contains multiple arrays of data to populate the stock chart. Each time I enter a symbol and click the "Get Quote" button it should fetch data from the web api, save/update  it under the Child Schema in the database. How can I do this with nodejs and mongoose? Here is the code that I tried....

**Folder - Models - Stock.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', { useNewUrlParser: true })
const slug = require('slug')


const childSchemaData = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: mongoose.Decimal128,
  open: mongoose.Decimal128,
  high: mongoose.Decimal128,
  low: mongoose.Decimal128,
  close: mongoose.Decimal128,
  volume: mongoose.Decimal128
})

const parentSchemaSymbol = new mongoose.Schema({
  symbol: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 4,
    required: 'Plese enter a valid symbol, min 2 characters and max 4'
  },
  // Array of subdocuments
  data: [childSchemaData],
  slug: String

});

//we have to PRE-save slug before save the parentSchemaSymbol into DB
parentSchemaSymbol.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified('symbol')) {
    next()//skip it
    return//stop this function from running
  }
  this.slug = slug(this.symbol)
  next()
  //TODO make more resiliant soslug are unique
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Stock', parentSchemaSymbol)
```

**Controller - webApiController.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const axios = require('axios')

require('../models/Stock')
const parentSchemaSymbol = mongoose.model('Stock')



mongoose.Promise = global.Promise // Tell Mongoose to use ES6 promises
// Connect to our Database and handle any bad connections
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', { useNewUrlParser: true })
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`        → ${err.message}`)
})

exports.webApi = (req, res) => {
  let curValue = req.params.symbol

  axios.get(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${curValue}&outputsize=compact&apikey=TUVR`)
    .then(response => {
      return highLow = Object.keys(response.data['Time Series (Daily)']).map(date => {
        return {
          date: Date.parse(date),
          open: Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['1. open']) * 100) / 100,
          high: Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['2. high']) * 100) / 100,
          low: Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['3. low']) * 100) / 100,
          close: Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['4. close']) * 100) / 100,
          volume: parseInt(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['5. volume'])
        }
      })

    })
    .then(_ => {

      let curValueSchema = new parentSchemaSymbol()

      curValueSchema.symbol = curValue
      highLow.map(item => {
        curValueSchema.data.push(item)
      })
      const query = { symbol: `${curValue.toUpperCase()}` }
      const update = { $addToSet: { data: [curValueSchema.data] } }
      const options = { upsert: true, new: true }
      curValueSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).then(doc => {
        console.log('Saved the symbol', doc)
        return res.send(highLow)
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

**Here is the piece of code that I am looking to fix. The rest is working:**

```
 let curValueSchema = new parentSchemaSymbol()

      curValueSchema.symbol = curValue
      highLow.map(item => {
        curValueSchema.data.push(item)
      })
      const query = { symbol: `${curValue.toUpperCase()}` }
      const update = curValueSchema
      const options = { upsert: true, new: true }
      curValueSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).then(doc => {
        console.log('Saved the symbol', doc)
        return res.send(highLow)
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
```

**Here is the error I am getting**

```
TypeError: curValueSchema.findOneAndUpdate is not a function
    at axios.get.then.then._ (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/controllers/webApiController.js:55:22)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:7)
```

**Here is the data  = highLow**

[image]

***SOLUTION***

Because Mongoose by default creates a new MongoDB ObjectId ( this hidden _id field) every time you pass it a Javascript Object to update the field of a document.

To go around you can tell Mongoose to not create a new ObjectId, by making sure your mongoose schema is as followed:

**Folder - Models - Stock.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', { useNewUrlParser: true })
const slug = require('slug')


const childSchemaData = new mongoose.Schema({
  "_id": false,
  date: mongoose.Decimal128,
  open: mongoose.Decimal128,
  high: mongoose.Decimal128,
  low: mongoose.Decimal128,
  close: mongoose.Decimal128,
  volume: mongoose.Decimal128
})

const parentSchemaSymbol = new mongoose.Schema({
  "_id": false,
  symbol: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 4,
    required: 'Plese enter a valid symbol, min 2 characters and max 4'
  },
  // Array of subdocuments
  data: [childSchemaData],
  slug: String

});

//we have to PRE-save slug before save the parentSchemaSymbol into DB
parentSchemaSymbol.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified('symbol')) {
    next()//skip it
    return//stop this function from running
  }
  this.slug = slug(this.symbol)
  next()
  //TODO make more resiliant soslug are unique
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Stock', parentSchemaSymbol)
```

**Controller - webApiController.js**

```
let curValueSchema = new parentSchemaSymbol()

      curValueSchema.symbol = curValue
      highLow.map(item => {
        curValueSchema.data.push(item)
      })
      const query = { symbol: `${curValue.toUpperCase()}` }
      const update = curValueSchema
      const options = { upsert: true, new: true }
      parentSchemaSymbol.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).then(doc => {
        console.log('Saved the symbol', doc)
        return res.send(highLow)
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. findOneAndUpdate and update is a model method and its available for instance of the model, So you're getting method not found error.

```js
let curValueSchema = new parentSchemaSymbol()
curValueSchema.symbol = curValue
highLow.map(item = > {
  curValueSchema.data.push(item)
})
const query = {
  symbol: `$ {
    curValue.toUpperCase()
  }`
}
const update = curValueSchema
const options = {
  upsert: true,
  new: true
}
parentSchemaSymbol.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).then(doc = > {
  console.log('Saved the symbol', doc)
  return res.send(highLow)
}).
catch (e = > {
  console.log(e)
})
```

Comment: Aha , it makes sence. But for same reason it does not work as expected. It is inserting dumplicate values and ```pre('save')``` is not working. Also  ```const query = { symbol: `${curValue.toUpperCase()}` }``` does not apply  ```toUpperCase()```

Comment: to avoid the duplication I need to add ```"_id": false``` to the child  and parent Schema

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
curValueSchema.findOneAndUpdate
```

Do:

```
parentSchemaSymbol.findOneAndUpdate
```

Comment: Aha , it makes sence. But for same reason it does not work as expected. It is inserting dumplicate values and pre('save') is not working. Also const query = { symbol: `${curValue.toUpperCase()}` } does not apply toUpperCase()

Comment: to avoid the duplication I need to add ```"_id": false``` to the child  and parent Schema

Answer (score 1):

It's a model's method, not a instance.
Replace instance name with scheme name.

Comment: Aha , it makes sence. But for same reason it does not work as expected. It is inserting dumplicate values and pre('save') is not working. Also const query = { symbol: `${curValue.toUpperCase()}` } does not apply toUpperCase()

Comment: to avoid the duplication I need to add ```"_id": false``` to the child  and parent Schema